# How to find the least number of weigh trials when trying to get a decimal amount?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, nonlinear-optimization

Does it exist a way to obtain a quick answer to this problem instead of just guessing?

The problem is as follows:

> A technician has only available a two pan scale to measure powdered
>   sucrose. The only calibrated weighs available in the lab are one of
>   $100\,g$. He is tasked to obtain $1.1\,kg$ of the sucrose from a bag
>   which has only $2.5\,kg$ of the sugar. What would be the least number
>   of weigh trials he can take to obtain the desired weight?.

The alternatives given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{4 trials}\\
2.&\textrm{3 trials}\\
3.&\textrm{2 trials}\\
4.&\textrm{6 trials}\\
\end{array}$

Does it exist a way to solve this kind of problem without just guessing?. I'm stuck in this situation. Can someone help me here?.

If you split in two halves $2.5\,kg$ you can have $1.25\,kg$ in both sides. This would be in one trial.

In a second trial $1.25$ can be in one side and in the other $1.15+0.10$ using the other weigh. But I end up having one bag with $1.15\,kg$.

In the following weigh: (Using the other sack and returning to it the unused $100$ grams)

$1.25+0.10=1.35\,kg$

But here is where I'm stuck at. Can someone help me?. **Does it exist an equation or something?.** It would help me a lot to get a step-by-step explanation for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem should really define what types of weighing are allowed.  My solution:

Put the 100g on one side and split the sugar until it balances.  You have 1.2kg with the weight and 1.3 kg on the other side

Move the weight to the other pan and remove sugar until it balances.  There is still 1.2 kg of sugar on the other pan, so we have 1.1 kg on the pan with the weight

2 weighings

I am not aware of any general procedure for things like this.  You are just supposed to be clever.

Answer (score 0):

First, put 100g to the left pan. Then add powder to both left and right pan such that they balance. This way, You will have 100g weigh + 1.2kg powder on the left pan and 1.3kg powder on the right pan.

Remove the 1.3kg powder from the right pan, keep the 1.2kg powder from the left pan. Keep the 100g weigh on the left pan.

Now try to add powder from remaining 1.2kg powder to the right pan so that it balance the 100g weigh on the left pan. This way You will add 100g powder to the right pan, and what does that left You? 1.1kg powder left :)

Now the method (maybe not really):

$2.5kg=25\times 0.1kg$ and $1.1kg=11\times0.1kg$

$25=2^{4}+2^{3}+2^{0}$ and $11=2^{3}+2^{1}+2^{0}=2^{3}+2^{2}-2^{0}$

In one trial i can do one of the followings:

1. Substract $2^{0}\times0.1kg$ of powder. (this is what i did for the second trial)
2. Reduce all power of 2 by 1, and removing the $2^{0}$. (this is what i did for the first trial, $12=2^{4-1}+2^{3-1}$)
3. Reduce all power of 2 by 1, and maintaining the $2^{0}$. (this is if i keep the 1.3kg instead of 1.2kg on my first trial, $13=2^{4-1}+2^{3-1}+2^{0}$)

That being said, i want to move from $2^{4}+2^{3}+2^{0}$ to $2^{3}+2^{2}-2^{0}$ using aforementioned steps. Thus i did step 2 for the first trial, then step 1 for the second trial.

Maybe not really what You expect of a method.

Comment: The unattended part on this question was that **if it exists** a method to solve this via an equation or some sort. How did you came to the conclusion of splitting the weigh?. Was it just guessing?. To probe the ground?. I don't get very well the idea of splitting the powdered and balancing. If you take a look into my attempt I tried doing this. But if you split the two, you end up with $1.25\,kg$. Adding $100\,g$ in one side will be $1.35\,kg$ and the other will have the same $1.35\,kg$. Can you help me with this part?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell this may be long so i will add some explanation to the answer

Comment: This might be required since I'm stuck on it.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell hey check out the edit i made. i could not really call this a method, but this is as close to a method i can possibly explain it

Comment: Gee it doesn't give me much confidence to use it in an exam. :( Probably in this sort of situation I would rather use a simplification other than just playing with powers of two. It would help better if you could include a schematic for the first trial and the second trial.